# Trim a value coming from an awk field

Tags: shell-script

I am parsing a file and I use awk to get the first and third field.

This is all good; but in the first field I would like to trim the last 4 char from that string; so far I didn't find a way to do this in awk, and the only way to do so, is to make multiple calls so I save the awk output in 2 variables, and then trim the first string.

Is there a more efficient way to do so? This is what the file look like

```
abcdefghi.234,12345,xyz
riosadsef.543,19432,eis
baifafsag.342,01934,eod
```

This is what I run in the loop

```
echo $output | awk -F, "{print $1, $3}"
```

This will print the line correctly, but then I want to trim $1, removing the last 4 chars

Comment: Your code with `$1` inside doublequotes `"` should not work as described; shell needs singlequotes `'` to include actual `$` in an argument. IF as per your example the unwanted characters always begin with `.` and `.` is not used elsewhere, you could treat both as field delimiters: `awk -F'[.,]' '{print $1,$4}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use awk's `substr` function.  For example, starting with this input:

```
$ cat input
abcdefghi.234,12345,xyz
riosadsef.543,19432,eis
baifafsag.342,01934,eod
```

We can print columns one and three, omitting the last four characters of column one with:

```
$ awk -F, '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-4), $3}' input
abcdefghi xyz
riosadsef eis
baifafsag eod
```

Comment: Awesome; I felt like there was a better way, instead than write 3 more lines and do the trimming on the variable value. Thanks!